# Name of attributes that are indirectly related to entity

Tags: terminology, naming-convention

If I have a set of data that relate to an entity directly and some that do not, is there a standard name for these two types of attributes?

example, Employee:

```
employeeID firstname lastname manager dept
123        boris     mctrump  gareth  sales
```

I would suggest that 'firstname' and 'lastname' directly relate to the employee but 'manager' and 'dept' are somehow indirect

Comment: Foreign key? At least if it's modeled "right", as managers and departments are entities on their own in my understanding (Managers are likely to be also employees but still that's an entity).

Comment: to me, "Key" implies a link to another table or dataset - which may not exist. Perhaps "core" and "extended" attributes is a better description? I don't know either way, seems like something like this should have a proper nomenclature